# INSERT INTO subtract 2 values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible for an INSERT query to subtract 2 values you have entered to create a 3rd value that can then be inserted into a table - if that makes sense...

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (column1, column2, column3)
VALUES ('50', '25', column1 - column2)
```

Comment: If this relationship should always exist between the three columns, you might be looking for a Computed Column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table1 (column1, column2, column3)
(select ('50', '25', column1 - column2) from table1 where conditions)
```

This is a sample query!  hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Convoluted:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (column1,column2,column3)
select column1,column2,column1-column2
from
    (select 50 as column1,
            25 as column2
    ) t
```

Since you can't reference other columns from the same `SELECT` clause, you have to do it as a subquery. I've also switched to using `int` literals rather than strings, because I can't make subtraction make sense in my head otherwise.

You could also do it using a [Table Value Constructor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

```
INSERT INTO table1 (column1,column2,column3)
select column1,column2,column1-column2
from
    ( VALUES (50, 25)
    ) AS t (column1, column2);
```

---

As indicated in my comment though, if the relationship should always hold, I'd build table1 as:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    column1 int not null,
    column2 int not null,
    column3 as column1 - column2
    --More columns
)
```

Because that way, the `column3` value is always correct.

Comment: @ypercube - thanks for the edit. I've added a link to the MSDN topic

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm going to re-create the column as this relationship will always exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can create function that subtracts values and use this function in insert. This is the right way to do such things:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (column1, column2, column3)
 (select ('50', '25', your_function() ) from table1 where conditions)
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the "INSERT INTO" would do this:

```
INSERT INTO Table1Name (column1, column2, column3,)
(select 'X', 'Y', X - Y as Z)
```

Here is a [link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/15/sql-server-insert-data-from-one-table-to-another-table-insert-into-select-select-into-table/) to SQL Authority with more examples of INSERT INTO

Answer (score 0):

Another method would to be add a trigger to the table, where on insert of data, the third column would be updated with the difference of the first two columns.